# Not every commutative semigroup is isomorphic with the multiplicative semigroup of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

This is a statement in [commutative algebra notes](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/614F15/614.pdf)

page 19.

First, the multiplicative semigroup associated with the a ring $R$ should be $(R-\{0\}, \times)$, in my opinion, but the author claims that for a commutative semigroup to be the multiplicative semigroup of a ring it should contain an element acting like $0$. Why?

Second, in the example given, the author uses the addition operation on the commutative multiplicative semigroup of $\{x^k, k \in N\}$, but how do you define addition for formal monomials?

Comment: Why shouldn't it include 0?  Nothing about a semigroup asks for inverses (or even an identity).  If something like "group of units" means the largest possible group made out of units, then "multiplicative semigroup" should mean something similar (and, including 0 doesn't destroy the semigroup axiom).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $R\setminus \{0\}$ is not always closed under multiplication, so it would not be a semigroup. It is *only* closed under multiplication when the ring is a domain. The only reasonable definition of the multiplicative semigroup of a ring $(R,+,\cdot)$ is $(R, \cdot)$.

Any example of a commutative semigroup without an absorbing element is an example of a semigroup that can't be the multiplicative semigroup of a ring.

The set $\{x^n|n\in\mathbb N\}$ is such a semigroup, because there is no element which absorbs multiplication by the rest.

Actually the author improves upon this by showing that you can even have a zero element and not have a ring (but that would spoil the answer to the next part of the question, so stay tuned below.)

> How do you define addition for formal monomials?

After a reading of the notes you are referencing, I have to say that this is the wrong question. There is no need to define addition for these. What the author is doing in that passage is taking $X=\{0\}\cup \{x^k\mid k\in\mathbb N\}$ and showing that if you suppose it has a ring structure (any ring structure at all) you arrive at a contradiction. The addition given to us by virtue of the supposition that "suppose $X$ is the multiplicative monoid of a ring."

Comment: Ah, you gave a better answer.  The good example is $\mathbb{Z}_4$ where $2 \cdot 2 = 0$.

Comment: For the second part of the question, the reason is that the notes uses element like $x^k+1$ without giving a meaning to it.

Comment: @z.z OK, well I can't speak to that. But I can see why the set of formal powers of $x$ is a relevant example for the semigroup.

Comment: Do you know how to make sense of those terms in terms of formal monomials?

Comment: @z.z I don't know what you mean by "make sense of those terms."  The author gave an example to show the claim is true... what is left to ask?

Comment: The author only defines multiplication for formal monomials, and he does not define addition for monomials.  In his notation, x^0 = 1, then essentially $x+1$ means $x^k + x^0$, but he does not really define addition for the multiplicative ring $\{x^k, k \in \mathbb N\}$.

Comment: @z.z Like I said, I do not see any point in defining addition on the monomials, since it irrelevant for the purposes of the example, and, without more context,  I am at a loss to explain why the author would have written "$x^k+1$". So... if you think it is important you will have to provide a picture or something. Maybe it is just a typo that you are lending too much importance to?

Comment: I am so sorry, cannot you see the link I posted?

Comment: @z.z Ah, I overlooked that in the mobile reader. He does not need to define an operation $+$. He is *supposing* that $\{0\}\cup\{x^k\mid k\in\mathbb N\}$ is a ring with whatever ring structure and whatever addition, and showing that a contradiction arises. This proves that the set as given cannot be made into a ring with multiplication that respects the monomial multiplication.

Comment: Got it, thanks!